# Validate array of 'from date' and 'to date' using javascript

Tags: javascript, date-comparison

I have a form to assign the user for the particular period and i can reassign the same user for the another period of time. I want to validate the user assigned date should not overlap.

Ex Form Fileds:

```
Name        From date       To date
User1       01-05-2014      10-05-2014
User2       01-05-2014      20-05-2014
User1       05-05-2014      20-05-2014 (This is Wrong Assignment. Need to alert)
```

Comment: Where are those assignments stored? How do you get them into your script (you don't need to read that CSV, do you)?

Comment: The assignments will store in MySQL DB. Thats not an issue now. I want to validate when user input by javascript.

Comment: OK, so you send the user input to the server to check in SQL? What *is* the issue you're having?

Comment: Jesus this is a terrible question, far too broad, are you asking somebody to write an entire front/back end with mysql. Break the problem down into smaller chunks and approach them individually, with SO questions if necessary.

Comment: Bergi-- Can you refer some example in Javascript validation

Comment: Sam am not asking entire code for this.

Answer (score 0):

Use dates in ISO format and you can use a string comparision.

```
var a = [
    [ "User1", "2014-05-01", "2014-05-10" ],
    [ "User2", "2014-05-01", "2014-05-20" ],
    [ "User1", "2014-05-05", "2014-05-20" ]
]

var overlaped = a.filter(function(row, index, arr) {
    for (var cur, pos = index; cur = arr[--pos];)
        if (cur[0] == row[0] && (
            (cur[1] >= row[1] && cur[1] <= row[2]) ||
            (cur[2] >= row[1] && cur[2] <= row[2]))) break;
    return -1 != pos
})
```